# choosing 5 numbers out of 20 - smallest is bigger than '5'

Tags: probability, combinatorics

What is the probability to choose $5$ numbers between $ 1,2..,20$ so the smallest number of them is bigger than $5$?

My answer:

we have $5\frac{1}{20}$ for the 5 #.
we have $\frac{20-5}{20}$ possible # that bigger than $5$.

we get $\frac13$.

correct?

Comment: How do you get $\frac 13$?

Comment: @RossMillikan, I think the OP has computed $1/3=(5/20)/(15/20)$ from the two preceding lines.  But those assertions indicate confusion about what needs to be computed.

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer is either

$$\left({15\over20}\right)^5\approx.2373$$

or

$${{15\choose5}\over{20\choose5}}={15\cdot14\cdot13\cdot12\cdot11\over20\cdot19\cdot18\cdot17\cdot16}\approx.1937$$

depending on whether you choose *with* or *without* replacement.  In either case, the key is that when you ask that the smallest number be greater than $5$, you are limiting yourself to a set of $15$ numbers in the initial set of $20$.

Things would perhaps be clearer if the problem didn't use the number $5$ in two different ways.  If instead it asked for the probability of choosing $k$ cards so that the smallest is bigger than $n$, then the answer would be either

$$\left({20-n\over20}\right)^k\qquad\text{or}\qquad{{20-n\choose k}\over{20\choose k}}$$

again depending on whether you're choosing the $k$ cards with or without replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Incorrect.

The smallest number is bigger than 5 precisely if all numbers are bigger than 5. The probability of a single number being bigger than 5 is $\frac34$, so the probability of all five numbers being bigger than 5 is $\big(\frac34\big)^5=\frac{243}{1024}$.

(Assuming a number can be picked multiple times.)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, a combinatorics approach (I'm assuming distinct, if not, there's a simple way to modify this):

There are ${20 \choose 5}$ total ways to choose 5 numbers. If we don't want anything less than or equal to 5, then the combinations we want are of the 15 numbers greater than 5. Thus ${15 \choose 5}$ ways exist. Take the ratio of the two terms and you're done.